# C++: derived classes and virtual methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C++ : implications of making a method virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821561/c-implications-of-making-a-method-virtual)
>   [Why is 'virtual' optional for overridden methods in derived classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963965/why-is-virtual-optional-for-overridden-methods-in-derived-classes)

I wonder, what is documented behavior in the following case:

You have

```
class A
{
 virtual void A()
 {
   cout << "Virtual A"<<endl;
 }
 void test_A()
 {
   A();
 }
}

class B: public A
{
  void A()
  {
   cout << "Non-virtual A in derived class"<<endl;
  }

  void test_B()
  {
    A();
  }
}

A a; B b;
a.test_A();
b.test_A();
b.test_B();
```

What it supposed to do according to C++ standard and why?
GCC works like B::A is also also virtual.

What shoudl happen in general when you override virtual method by non-virtual one in derived class?

Comment: Your code [shouldn't compile](http://ideone.com/gI9bI).

Comment: I think this is also answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963965/why-is-virtual-optional-for-overridden-methods-in-derived-classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sub-class member function is implicitly virtual if a virtual base-class member function with the same name and signature exists.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please explain, I want to learn.

Comment: You need to look at the code more carefully. BTW I haven't downlvoted.

Comment: The code is not working, I see that, but I answered the question that was asked in the last line. And with respect to that, my answer is correct.

Comment: I see. I have upvoted to counterbalance. BTW use the words `member function` instead of `method` in C++. C++ and Java are different.

Answer (score 2):

The code should not compile as you cannot name a method with the name of the class. But regarding what I understand that is your real question:

> Will making a method virtual imply that the same method in all the derived classes is virtual even if the `virtual` keyword is not present?

The answer is yes. Once a method is declared virtual in a class, then all overrides of that method will be virtual, and the `virtual` keyword is optional in derived classes (even if I recommend typing it, if only for documentation purposes). Note that for a method in a derived class to be an override it has to have the same name and signature, with only potential difference being a covariant return type:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};
struct base {
   virtual A* foo();
   virtual A* bar();
};
struct derived : base {
   virtual B* foo();    // override, covariant return type
   virtual int bar();   // not override, return type is not covariant
   virtual A* bar(int); // not override, different argument list
};
```

Comment: Yes: I guess so. The last part of the question is exactly that. +1

Answer (score 0):

According to standard it should be

```
A a; B b;
a.test_A();  //"Virtual A"
b.test_A(); //Non-virtual A in derived class
b.test_B(); //Non-virtual A in derived class
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is ill-formed. A constructor cannot have a return type (as you have done for the constructor of 'A'). Also a constructor cannot be virtual.

After fixing A's constructor, class B is ill-formed as the constructor of A is private.

So, there are many problems with this code (including missing semicolons at the class definitions).